# Running Indy pool on a VM with only FQDN

Tags: docker, hyperledger-indy

I am trying to run the indy pool on a VM which does not have a static IP. It has a Fully Qualified Domain Name. When I run the pool on a VM with a static IP, I use [this](https://github.com/hyperledger/indy-sdk/blob/master/README.md#2-starting-the-test-pool-on-a-specific-ip-address) method with the IP of the VM while specifying the port mapping. This IP will be mentioned in the pool configuration and I am able to connect to the pool properly.

In the case of the VM without the static IP, I tried to do the same using the FQDN. like this

```
docker run -itd -p target=<FQDN>:9701-9708,publish=9701-9708 indy_pool
```

however, I got an error `docker: Invalid ip address:...<FQDN>`

How can I run the indy pool on this VM and connect using the mobile app.